# app store issue with sales and trends

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Right now in application on itunesconnect I have a lot of data in Sales And Trends section (about downloads and payments).

But I need to transfer my application to another itunesconnect account (I need to change the company for the application. So in the details of the application I choose More->Transfer).

**Will I have all that data in the other itunesconnect account after transferring the application or will I loose all that data about downloading and payments and so on?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

> Because you won’t be able to view the app information after the
>   transfer, make a catalog report (see Requesting Catalog Reports), note
>   dates the app was available on the store (see Viewing Status History),
>   and save sales and download information (see Viewing Sales and
>   Trends).

[Apple Documentation Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)